# JAX-WS client authentication on proxy server

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jax-ws

I'm trying to use JAX-WS api to send some soap messages on a client application. However, I'm behind a firewall and the only option is to use a proxy server to go outside.

I'm trying to find on google any answer about this and so far all fail: To Use `System.setProperty` for `http.proxyHost`, `http.proxyPort`, `http.proxyUser`, `http.proxyPassword`. To use Authenticator like is described [here](http://blog.vinodsingh.com/2008/05/proxy-authentication-in-java.html).

I'm running out of options, if someone could help me on this would be great.

Also, I have a option to use `org.apache.commons.httpclient` but then I need to generate manually the XML. So could you suggest any other approach or API for WS?

Comment: You should provide samples of what you tried with matching errors.

Comment: don't you have http access behind the firewall? Can't you browse the Internet behind it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ws import command when creating web client to configure proxy.

-httpproxy::

use above command to configure proxy.

How to do this depend on your IDE.

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.wsfep.multiplatform.doc/info/ae/ae/rwbs_wsimport.html

Answer (score 0):

For Jax-ws webservice client, use the following

```
//set proxy info to the ClientProxyFeature
ClientProxyFeature cpf = new ClientProxyFeature();
cpf.setProxyHost("proxyhost");
cpf.setProxyPort(8888);
cpf.setProxyUserName("proxyuser");
cpf.setProxyPassword("proxypwd");

//get the port with the Feature
MyPort port = myService.getPort(cpf);
```